# Prevent CRLF text being converted to LF text when downloading file with HttpClient.GetStreamAsync

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to download a file from Github and save it to a specific folder.

The code below works, but it converts the line endings in my file from CRLF to LF.

I want to keep the CRLF line endings.

When I download the file manually from Github, the file’s line endings remain as CRLF.

**Here's my code for calling the text file:**

```cs
string AlinktofileCM = destinationOnGithub + "mytext.txt";
string linktofileCM = destinationOnMyPc + "mytext.txt";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var s = client.GetStreamAsync(AlinktofileCM))
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(linktofileCM, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            s.Result.CopyTo(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

All the solutions I have found are related to webclient, I don't want to use it!

Comment: Well, that's certainly weird. I would have thought that the CR and LF would be treated as just another pair of characters in the stream!

Comment: If you download the same files manually and with your app, do you get different file sizes on disk?

Comment: When you say "download manually", do you mean "right click on a link and click 'Save as ...'", or are you opening the file by clicking on it?

Comment: When I say manually, it's by clicking the green button on my repo. Also on Github my files 3ko each and on my pc 2ko each.

Comment: If you download a given file manually, and call it (say) "A.txt", and then download the file with your app and call it (say) "B.txt", do the files have the same size on your PC?

Comment: Same result! I also forget to specify in my .gitattributes I added this * text eol=crlf

Comment: Ok, the problem comes from Github, when I download with the green button the file remains intact because it is zipped, I guess. However, if I go directly to my .txt file on Github and download it by right clicking on my mouse, the file is changed to LF.

Comment: github has some "magic" running on line-endings https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings